# Flutter WEB Showing Operation error on Hot Reload or Run with the same screen open

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-dependencies

Error Showing while hot reloading / restarting the flutter web

```
 Error: OperationError
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 299:10  createErrorWithStack
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 355:28            _throw
    dart-sdk/lib/core/errors.dart 120:5                                           throwWithStackTrace
    dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1385:11                                          callback
    dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
    dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15           <fn>
```

Comment: Hi, any idea how to solve this?